# Comparing a variable defined from angularJS controller in HTML page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to AngularJS so hopefully this is easy, I have the following HTML where I am trying to check if a current page is equal to zero and if so, I changed the class name of the tag to disabled. (currentPage is defined to be zero in my controller)

```
<script>
    if ('{{currentPage}}' == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prev").className = "disabled";
    }
    if ('{{currentPage}}' >= '{{eventslist}}'.length / '{{pageSize}}' - 1) {
        document.getElementById("next").className = "disabled";
    }
</script>
```

However, whenever I try to do a check like this, it never sees currentPage as zero. So then I added an else statement just to see what currentPage actually is.

```
<script>
    if ('{{currentPage}}' == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prev").className = "disabled";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("prev").innerHTML = "{{currentPage}}";
    }
    if ('{{currentPage}}' >= '{{eventslist}}'.length / '{{pageSize}}' - 1) {
        document.getElementById("next").className = "disabled";
    }
</script>
```

After doing this, sure enough, it does come back as zero. Any ideas why the if statement fails on something so simple? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Why not to put this code inside the controller and use `$scope` for working with local variables?

Comment: Have you gone through the Angular JS tutorial on the home page? I think you need to get a better understanding of how Angular is incorporated into a web app before trying to do this. For starters I've never seen binding in a script block before...

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because your script block is trying to compare the literal string {{currentPage}} to 0: Angular hasn't had a chance to do its thing before the browser tries to interpret the inline `<script>` block.     The correct way to do this would be to put all this logic in an Angular directive; then you won't need to muck about with direct DOM manipulation like innerHTML.

Comment: I clearly have some researching and more learning to do, thanks for the responses. @LeeWillis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="prev" ng-class="{'disabled': currentPage === 0}">
<span ng-if="currentPage !== 0">{{currentPage}}</span>
</div>
<div id="next" ng-class="{'disabled': currentPage >= eventsList.length / pageSize - 1}"></div>
```